# WooCommerce Subscriptions Hooks

Tags: templates, woocommerce, hook, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am currently customising a WooCommerce My Account, and I have been able to use the various WooCommerce hooks to customise the individual pages.

Using visual hook guides/references online I have found the hooks such as, `'woocommerce_before_edit_account_address_form'` and `'woocommerce_after_edit_account_address_form'`.

Are there any hooks to be able to add content before and/or after to the '**woocommerce subscriptions**' page in my account section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may copy this file `/woocommerce-subscriptions/templates/myaccount/my-subscriptions.php` to your active theme `woocommerce/myaccount/my-subscriptions.php`

You can add the content in this template.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didnt even think about looking at the files! Will review tomorrow and update this post.

Comment: @Aliqua  It's tested OK - Added screenshot. Is that what you are looking for.?

Comment: Yes, just read the code - there are no hooks so your solution is the most appropriate.